# Liferay json web services authentication

Tags: liferay

I want to integrate liferay with my existing application, for that i want to use JSON web services offered by liferay, Most of these services (listed at /api/jsonws) ask for authentication token "p_auth", however i don't find any log in or authenticate method in these services which can give me this p_auth token.

My application is php and i am not expert in java, so looking for some REST and/or SOAP based http method to log in/authenticate. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liferay added `p_auth` key to links marked with `@ActionMapping` annotation for preventing CSRF attacks. You can disable this token with

```
auth.token.check.enabled=false
```

on the Liferay side (portal-ext.properties file), but in this case anyone could be able to log in in such method.

You can read more [here](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authentication+Token)